# How to zip files from folder but keep it separated

Tags: c#, dotnetzip

I have 1 folder that contains many txt files. I want to zip them but separated.

Example:
In this folder I have *A.txt*, *B.txt*, *C.txt*.

I want to zip all the files but separated so the result will be *A.zip*, *B.zip*, *C.zip*.

```cs
string outputPath = "C:\\Users\\Desktop\\VA";
string path = outputPath + "\\VA_" + tglskrg;
foreach (string dirFile in Directory.GetDirectories(path))
{
    foreach (string fileName in Directory.GetFiles(dirFile))
    {
        using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
        {
            zip.UseUnicodeAsNecessary = true;
            zip.AddFile(); //dont know what to put
            zip.Save(); //dont know what to put
        }
    }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

I'm using dotnetzip (Ionic.zip) and C# Visual Studio Express 2010.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do that as follows:

```
foreach (string fileName in Directory.GetFiles(dirFile))
{
    var zipFile = Path.Combine(outputPath, Path.ChangeExtension(fileName, ".zip"));
    using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
    {
        zip.AddFile(fileName); // add A.txt to the zip file
        zip.Save(zipFile); // save as A.zip
    }
}
```

This takes all the files found in the folder `dirFile`, and saves them under `outputPath`, with the same file name but replacing the extension with `.zip`.

Comment: Welp, I have pretty much exactly the same but you were 20 secs faster. Tough luck, I'll delete mine.

Comment: sry for late reply, just arrive in office , thankyou so much for this , it really works